# Setting error text in Commerce Alter Form Module

Tags: forms, commerce

I need to validate my form and return a specific error message if the terms of agreement checkbox isn't checked (it's a required field). So I've placed the following code in my CommerceAlter.module. However, it's not working (ie. the error text is still showing the default error text):

```
function CommerceAlter_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (form_get_errors()) {
    $form_errors = form_get_errors();
    $drupal_errors = drupal_get_messages('error');

    // Clear form errors
    form_clear_error();

    foreach($drupal_errors['error'] as $key => $error) {
        if (in_array($error, $form_errors)) {
            // Unset form errors
            unset($drupal_errors['error'][$key]);
        }
    }

    // Rebuild drupal errors
    foreach($drupal_errors['error'] as $key => $message) {
        drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
    }

    // Validate form field and set error message    
    if ( $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']
['field_i_have_read_and_i_agree_to']['und']['0']['value'] === 0 ) {

            form_set_error('value', t('You forgot to check the required 
checkbox. Please try again.'));
        }
      }
    }
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can obtain the field value using this.

```
if ( $form_state['values']['field_i_have_read_and_i_agree_to'] == 0 ) {
  //or use this in if statement $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['field_i_have_read_and_i_agree_to']

      form_set_error('field_i_have_read_and_i_agree_to', t('You forgot to check the required checkbox.Please try again.'));
    }
```

You shouldn't include `['customer_profile_billing']` unless you have set the `#tree` to TRUE.

Comment: hmmm...I'm basing the whole field name off what's available in dpm($form_state) and that's showing the value as being in the following array: values > customer_profile_billing > field_i_have_read_and_i_agree_to > und > 0 >value 0. I guess I don't understand your #tree comment. I tried what you gave me and it still doesn't work.